# Почему не меняется label при смене значения в ModelMetadata

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Всем привет. Есть такая вот модель

```
public class User 
{
    [Display(Name="Name")]
    public string NameUser { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Messages")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Есть строготипизированная вьюха этой моделью с таким участком кода.

```
            @{ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(M=>M.DisplayName=="Messages").First().DisplayName = "Test";}

            @using(Html.BeginForm())
            {
                @Html.LabelFor(x=>x.NameUser)<br />
                @Html.LabelFor(x=>x.Message)<br />
            }
```

Я ожидаю, что так как `LabelFor` берет данные из заполненного `ViewData.ModelMetadata`, то изменяя свойство `DisplayName`, соответственно будет изменено и отображение текста выводимого `LableFor`, однако текст выводится тот , что указан в атрибуте, а не тот который я пытаюсь ему подставить. Почему ?

Answer (score 1):

В твоем случае надо использовать атрибут DisplayName:

```
public class User 
{
    [DisplayName("Name")]
    public string NameUser { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Messages")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

более подробно описано [тут](http://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/mvc/level6/6_5.php).